# How to pass boolean parameter in service call

Tags: android, service, adb

So I have been working with some service in Lollipop (applicable to others), and have noticed that the adb shell service call ... does not have a boolean data type. Does anyone know how I would test a system service that receives a boolean data type from adb?

E.G. System Service (IPowerManager.aidl)

```
...
boolean setPowerSaveMode(boolean mode); //14th entry
...
```

so the command should look like:

```
$ adb shell service call power 14 __ __
```

I assume it has something to do with passing an interger value (in c, val>0 == true), but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `i32 0` to pass `false` and `i32 1` to pass `true`

```
$ adb shell service call power 14 i32 1
```

Just make sure you are not sending that `setPowerSaveMode()`command over USB - the power saving mode won't turn on while the device is charging.

Comment: This was my initial assumption, but having a verification is what I was searching for. Thank you!